# Appropriate Use of Relations for User/Content Relationship

Tags: parse-platform

I have a user class and a point class.

Within the user class are several relations to keep up with user interactions with points including "MarkedAsRead", "upVoted", and "downVoted".

Read points are plotted with different colors than new points.
When I want to plot points, I query from the point class as well as the MarkedAsRead relation for to create two unique arrays. 
I then compare the two arrays- I search and remove points the user has already read from my points array to create and "unread" array.
I then draw the "unread" array and "markedAsRead" array to the map with respective colors.

To no surprise, this process of comparing the two arrays on the client side is taking a lot of time and slowing down my applications.

Does anyone have any recommendations? Should I be structuring my database differently? Am I using relations incorrectly?
Should I be creating an "unread" relation? If so, whats the best way to populate it?

```
NSMutableIndexSet *indexesToDelete = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSet];
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [readPoints count]; i++) 
{
     Point *point = readPoints[i];
     point.isRead = YES;
     for (NSInteger j = 0; j < [Points count]; j++) 
     {
         Point *otherPoint = Points[j];
         otherPoint.isRead = NO;
         if ([point.objectId isEqualToString:otherPoint.objectId]) 
         {
             [indexesToDelete addIndex:j];
         }
     }
 }
 [Points removeObjectsAtIndexes:indexesToDelete];
```

Comment: Comparing arrays client side should be super fast, given that you'll have at most 1000 items in each array since that is the query limit. Can you show how you're doing the comparison?

Comment: added code to original post.